# spiders to iterately find a html

Tags: python, html, web-crawler, brute-force

I want to access a website with the form of example.com/<num>-<num>.html

but I don't know the exact number in the url.

the numbers could go from 0 to 10000 or more.

I wrote a small python script to do this, but I feel it is very slow.

Are there some existing tools that could do the job?

```
for n in range(0,10000):
  print("n",n)
  for m in range(0,10000):     
      r = url+str(n)+str('-')+str(m)+str('.html')
      
      html = requests.get(r,headers=headers)
      try:
        html.raise_for_status()
      except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        continue
        #print(r+" doesn't exist")
      print(r)
```

also this code neglect the possibility of strings like 0012, which kind of bad

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a folder containing the code of the thing you want to make.
In order to have the numbers, you have to name the folder that number. I commonly do this with websites with certain sub-pages. But if this is like a social media site with numbered labeled posts, I don't know what to do.

Comment: There is only one valid website, the rest doesn't exist. It is just that I don't know what it is. So it is more or less like a brute force guessing.